# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in submitting a form in Laravel

Tags: php, forms, laravel

i am trying to submit a form to update the tbl_pages column. So to update the specific columns i using checkbox. Here is how my view looks like.

Here is how my **view** looks like:

```
    {!!Form::open([
            'method' => 'patch',
            'route' => 'pages.update'
        ])!!} 

    <p>{!! Form::checkbox('pages[]', $page->id, false, array('class' => 'checkboxes')) !!}</p>

 {!!Form::submit('Move to Trash', array('class' => 'btn btn-default', 'name'=> 'movetrash'))!!}

{!!Form::close()!!}
```

My **update()** method in **PageController.php** looks like this.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        if(Input::get('movetrash')) {
            $pagesarray = Input::get('pages'); //getting checkbox values from view
            if(!empty($pagesarray)){
                foreach($pagesarray as $pageid){
                    $page = Pages::where('id', $pageid) -> first();
                    $page -> active = 0;
                    $page -> save();
                }
                \Session::flash('movedtotrash', 'Pages has been successfully MOVED TO TRASH');
            } 
            return redirect()->route('pages');
        }

    }
```

And here how my **routes.php** looks like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web'], 'prefix' => 'pages'], function () {
    //
    Route::get('trash', 'PagesController@trashpage');

    Route::get('movetotrash/{id}', 'PagesController@movetotrash');

    Route::get('restore/{id}', 'PagesController@restore');

    Route::get('trashmultiple', [
            'as' => 'pages.trashmultiple', 'uses' => 'PagesController@update'
    ]);

    Route::resource('', 'PagesController'); // here is the problem

});
```

Here in the routes.php i feel i am **not able to define** `Route::resource('pages', 'PagesController');` like this, even if i do then i get this error `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php`

I guess this is problem that i am not able to do like this in my FORM `'route' => 'pages.update'`

Any solution for this will be really helpful.

Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 0):

update route needs an id. run `php artisan route:list` to see url of route associated with update (and if it exists). also use `Route::resource('/', 'PagesController');`

```
 {!!Form::open([
        'method' => 'patch',
        'route' => [pages.update, $id]
    ])!!}
```

Comment: How i will set $id? I am getting the value from the form itself. The checkbox name is "pages"

Comment: In that case javascript is your best bet (or jQuery). capture `Ajax` request and change url to the respective id.

Comment: I got it resolved i created a sub group and assign the property to that. It worked!